# A beginner Using count and getting errors

Tags: count, having

I am very new to SQL.. I have two tables.. contacts and addresses.. trying to see where the contact has multiple addresses that are marked as home.

I want to show information from both tables where the ra.cv__Contact__c (address) is the same for multiple records and the records say Address Type is home. When I remove my count function line I do see all the records that have a address marked as home, but when I put in

```
FROM dbo.cv__Related_Address_Detail__c ra LEFT JOIN dbo.Contact c on c.Id=ra.cv__Contact__c
WHERE ra.cv__Contact__c=ra.cv__Contact__c AND ra.cv__Address_Type__c='home' 
HAVING COUNT (ra.cv__Contact__c)>1
ORDER BY ra.cv__Contact__c;``
```

I get this error

Column 'dbo.cv__Related_Address_Detail__c.cv__Contact__c' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

and when I add group by

```
FROM dbo.cv__Related_Address_Detail__c ra LEFT JOIN dbo.Contact c on c.Id=ra.cv__Contact__c
WHERE ra.cv__Contact__c=ra.cv__Contact__c AND ra.cv__Address_Type__c='home' 
GROUP BY ra.cv__Contact__c
HAVING COUNT (ra.cv__Contact__c)>1
ORDER BY ra.cv__Contact__c;
```

I get

Column 'dbo.cv__Related_Address_Detail__c.Contact_VIS_Number__c' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 514
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Help

Comment: What do you want help with? The errors tell you what the problem is. a) selecting something not in the group and b) order by something not in the group.  Think it out.  What are you expecting?

Comment: I dont understand the error.. The first error said I needed to Group By.. When I used group by it gave me another error. I removed order by I still get the first part of that error.. sorry i just dont understand the error. 

I am really not looking to group.. I just want to only see those who have >1 address that is marked as home.. No matter how I try the count gives me an error..

Answer (score 0):

So it took a few different ways but I figured out that the problem is simply that i am trying to output too many fields that are not being aggregated..

so i bracketed my fields and did another inner join to get the count

```
SELECT c.id, COUNT(ra.id) 'Count'
FROM dbo.cv__Related_Address_Detail__c ra JOIN dbo.Contact c on 
c.Id=ra.cv__Contact__c
WHERE ra.cv__Address_Type__c='Home'
GROUP BY c.Id
Having COUNT(ra.id)>1
)prime
ON c.id=prime.Id
```